# mongodb c# API V2: Difference between ReplaceOne and FindOneAndReplace

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Looking a the mongodb documentation I read that FindOneAndReplace would be an ATOMIC operation. But what I don't understand is why ReplaceOne wouldn't be atomic? And if there is a difference why should one use ReplaceOne at all?

Comment: `FindOneAndReplace` uses `findAndModify` explicitly. `ReplaceOne` doesn't.

Comment: But what does that mean for the result?

Comment: importantly, which is faster?

Answer (score 4):

The documentation unveils a different method signature:

[ReplaceOne](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.10/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoCollection_1_ReplaceOne.htm):

```cs
ReplaceOneResult ReplaceOne(
    FilterDefinition<TDocument> filter,
    TDocument replacement,
    ReplaceOptions options = null,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = null
)
```

[FindOneAndReplace](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.10/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoCollection_1_FindOneAndReplace__1.htm):

```cs
TProjection FindOneAndReplace<TProjection>(
    FilterDefinition<TDocument> filter,
    TDocument replacement,
    FindOneAndReplaceOptions<TDocument, TProjection> options = null,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = null
)
```

Most notably the return type and the options parameter differ.

While `ReplaceOne` returns a [ReplaceOneResult](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.10/apidocs/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_ReplaceOneResult.htm), `FindOneAndReplace` returns a document (be aware of the ReturnDocument property in the options).

The [`ReplaceOptions`](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.10/apidocs/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_ReplaceOptions.htm) are rather limited compared to [`FindOneAndReplaceOptions`](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.10/apidocs/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_FindOneAndReplaceOptions_2.htm), e.g. the former does not provide a `sort` property to give you control over which document will be the first of the matching documents in the collection. This doesn't matter if you filter based on an ID, but if you want to replace the latest document the sort option is very useful.

(Side note: I personally find the documentation here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.replaceOne/ and here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndReplace/ much more helpful, as they explain the usage in more detail and also provide some examples. But I don't know how closely it matches the MongoDB C# driver.)

Comment: which is faster?

Comment: ReplaceOne, doesn't load the document back to the client.  And internally doesn't load extra functions Eg for sorting. 

But now you can use a hint to specify an index to use.

If you wan't max performance and won't need the replaced document use replaceOne.

Note: you can disable the document return using findOneAndReplace with returnNewDocument option