# Mongo c# ReplaceOne and FindOneAndReplace

Tags: c#, mongodb, replace

What is the difference between

```
  IMongoCollection<TDocument>.ReplaceOne(filter, newDocument)
```

and

```
  IMongoCollection<TDocument>.FindOneAndReplace(filter, newDocument)
```

in official mongo c# driver

Answer (score 1):

I assume they correspond to mongodb operations of the same names.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.replaceOne/
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndReplace/

Regarding the difference of those, see here:

[mongodb c# API V2: Difference between ReplaceOne and FindOneAndReplace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36895238/mongodb-c-sharp-api-v2-difference-between-replaceone-and-findoneandreplace)